# Remove variable in constraint

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

Assume that i have one optimize problem as the example below, i want to fix x = 1 then change the constrain? how can I do it? Is there have some library?

```
import pulp as pulp
from pulp import *


x = LpVariable("x", cat= LpBinary)
y = LpVariable("y", cat= LpBinary)
z = LpVariable("z", cat= LpBinary)
k = LpVariable("k", cat= LpBinary)
prob = LpProblem("myProblem", LpMinimize)

#x.fixed = 1

prob += x + y + z + k, "myProblem"

prob += x + 3*y + 2*k >= 4
prob += 3*x + 2*y - 4*z + 6*k <= 30
prob += 5*x + y <= 10


status = prob.solve()

print(LpStatus[status])
print(value(x))
print(value(y))
print(value(z))
print(value(k))
```

i try to fix by using x.fixed but it not work, I want to fixed then it will be the new problem

Comment: `prob += 1 <= x <= 1`?

Comment: i mean if i fix randomly, the constraints will change base on that variable

Comment: What does _fix randomly_ even mean? Fixing this variable would be done with the bound arguments on its construction.

Comment: like you know, if my problem has 4 variables x, y, z, k and some constraints. the solver will find the optimal solution, right? 
But now i want to fix value of x (or y, z, k randomly) to 1 (or 0) then i want my contraints change base on that variable
example: 1st constraint is : x + 3y + 2k >= 4, now i want it convert to 1 + 2y +z >= 4
but i do not know how to fix and change them automatically, if the problem has 100+ variable so what should i do? i do not want to add more constraints, it like i fix some variables, change the constraints and dont care about that variables

Answer (score 0):

Make an inner solution routine that accepts an optional fix value:

```py
from typing import Literal

import pulp as pulp


def solve(x_fix: None | Literal[0, 1] = None) -> list[int]:
    x = pulp.LpVariable(
        name='x', cat=pulp.LpInteger,
        lowBound=0 if x_fix is None else x_fix,
        upBound=1 if x_fix is None else x_fix,
    )
    y = pulp.LpVariable(name='y', cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    z = pulp.LpVariable(name='z', cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    k = pulp.LpVariable(name='k', cat=pulp.LpBinary)

    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='myProblem', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
    prob.objective = x + y + z + k
    prob.addConstraint(x + 3*y + 2*k >= 4)
    prob.addConstraint(3*x + 2*y - 4*z + 6*k <= 30)
    prob.addConstraint(5*x + y <= 10)
    
    prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
    if prob.status != pulp.LpStatusOptimal:
        raise ValueError(f'Status {prob.status}')

    return [round(v.value()) for v in (x, y, z, k)]


print('  Variable:', solve())
print('Fixed at 0:', solve(0))
print('Fixed at 1:', solve(1))
```

```
  Variable: [0, 1, 0, 1]
Fixed at 0: [0, 1, 0, 1]
Fixed at 1: [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: i'm mean, if i fix x = 1 (or 0) the solver will not solve x. Like after i fix -> constraints change base on it -> solve the rest variables. x now is not a variable anymore. But my problem have 100+ variable, i dont know how to do automatically

Comment: Do _what_ automatically? Are you saying that you want to find a solution, fix a variable at the output of the solution, and iterate until all variables are fixed? Because... that won't do anything at all different from just solving the problem once.

Comment: i'm mean, after i fix x, i want the constraints change base on it, after that I want to remove x out of the solver. Like i have the constraint x + 3*y + 2*k >= 4 then it become 3*y + 2*k >= 3. Now the solver only need to solve y, z, k

Comment: I think you have some deep misconception about how linear programming solvers function. Doing what you describe will not produce effects any different from simply solving the problem once. There is absolutely no point to iterative fixing of the kind you describe. When you say that the constraints change... _they don't. They produce results that are mathematically identical_ between the cases where no variables are fixed, or variables are fixed at their optimal value.

Comment: How do you know what value to fix your variable at? If it's taken as the optimal value from a previous iteration, don't do any of this and just solve the problem once. If it's something else, you need to explain exactly how you're choosing your fix values.